# Помогите допилить PHP скрипт удаления файлов

Tags: php, файлы

Есть скрипт, он удалет все файлы, которые прожили больше 24 часа.

```
<?php
$dir = "./";
$files = scandir( $dir );
$time = time();
$life_file = 86400;
$time = $time - $life_file;
foreach( $files as $file )
{
if( $file != "." && $file != ".." )
{
    $file = $dir.$file;
    $filemtime = filemtime( $file ); 
      if( $filemtime <= $time )
        {
        unlink( $file );
       }
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Проблема в том, что он удаляет сам себя.

Как сделать так, что бы он не удалял сам себя, и ещё парочку файлов (catalog.txt, style.css) ?

Посоветовали на баше комнду: **find ./ -type  f -mtime +1 ! -name script_name -delete** , но не работает.

Так же хотел сделать так:

```
<?php
$dir = "./";
$files = scandir( $dir );
$time = time();
$life_file = 86400;
$time = $time - $life_file;
foreach( $files as $file )
 {
if( $file != "." && $file != ".." )
 {
    $file = $dir.$file;
    $filemtime = filemtime( $file ); 
    if( $filemtime <= $time )
       {
        system ("ls | grep -v index.php .htacces | xargs rm -rfv");
       }
     }
  }
 ?>
```

Но это бред какой-то... Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    <?php
$dir = "./";
$files = scandir( $dir );
$time = time();
$life_file = 86400;
$time = $time - $life_file;
$ignore = array('.', '..', basename(__FILE__), 'catalog.txt', 'style.css');
foreach( $files as $file )
{
if( !in_array($file, $ignore) )
{
    $file = $dir.$file;
    $filemtime = filemtime( $file ); 
      if( $filemtime <= $time )
        {
        unlink( $file );
       }
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: цикломатическую сложность можно уменьшить таким образом `if( in_array($file, $ignore) ) continue;`

Comment: Привычки - это не всегда хорошо. Зачастую два-три простых условия с `continue`/`break` делают код на порядок читабельней и понятней, чем горный пик из вложенностей

Comment: Благодарю. Оказываеться всё очень просто :-/